# How can I use :focus when browsers behave differently? Chrome shows :focus style after click on buttons. Firefox keeps it on links

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, accessibility

Ideally the `:focus` style should only be visible when using <kbd>tab</kbd> but Firefox and Chrome also display it after a click. Additionally, [Firefox and Chrome differ in their focus behavior on click](http://codepen.io/bfred-it/full/zHqDt): Firefox keeps the focus on **links** while Chrome keeps it on **buttons**.

```
<a href="/page">This links stays focused after a click in Firefox</a>
<button>This button stays focused after a click in Chrome</button>
```

This behavior becomes a problem:

- in Firefox: `:focus` overrides a class indicating the current page in a menu
- in Chrome: buttons stay "on" for no apparent reason after being clicked

A possible solution would be to normalize the behavior (kind of) across browsers by blurring the clicked elements.

```
function blurElement () {
  this.blur();
}
//I'm using onmouseup because onclick is also fired on [enter]
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].onmouseup = blurElement;
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].onmouseup = blurElement;
```

**Would this be ok?** Does accessibility suffer?

[Demo, test tables, real-world scenarios and possible fix on CodePen](http://codepen.io/bfred-it/full/zHqDt)

Comment: After clicking a link or a button you'd _usually_ be leaving the page so the focus doesn't matter. These days you would _want_ focus to go to the most recent thing clicked, so a `tab` would take you to the next place after that.  If you tab to a button it gets focus; how should it look then? It should look the same as having focus after being clicked.  You may want to change your styles here to use `:active` rather than `:focus`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, can't comment because I'm new to stackoverflow. I would want a bit of clarification on your particular use case, but here's a general answer.

**A Element**

You should never use the 'a' tag for anything that isn't an actual link i.e. it goes to another page, or goes to a name linked (using #namedlinked), both of which change your focus anyway. If you're changing something within a page (e.g. show/hide link, web app navigation), you should always use a button even if you style it to look like a link.

So really, this goes back to the guideline that you should be using the HTML elements in a semantically correct way if you want your site to be accessible.

**Button**

When you have buttons, the Chrome behaviour such as in the slideshow example of the codepen is not incorrect. Don't forget that in the list of pseudo-classes, aside from :hover, and :focus, there is also :active.

Here's a simple example:

```
button:focus {
  border-color: green;
  color: green;
}
button.a:active {
  background: red;
}
```

Something like this will always have styling on focus (before or after clicking), and then any buttons with the "a" class will make your button red when clicking on it. See quick demo at http://jsfiddle.net/434ps28f/5/

This works exactly the same way for me in both Chrome and Firefox (latest Windows versions).

As to the other example where :focus overrides .current. It should do that as long as the user has focus on that element. That's how the user knows they still have focus there. Once the focus moves off of that element .current is still applied.

I don't suggest it, but if for some reason you want the user to see the .current styling regardless of whether they have focus, then you could add an extra rule:

```
.current {
   border-color: orange;
}
.current:focus {
  border-color: orange;
}
```

See [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/434ps28f/5/)

Comment: • I already use HTML elements semantically on sites: `a` elements link to pages normally, but on JS-enabled browsers the content loads via XHR below the buttons. • `:active` is something different. The issue here is about offering a `:focus` style without it interfering with other functionality — i.e. `:hover` or `.current`, like used in the linked example

Comment: :focus doesn't seem to interfere with :hover at least. As to something like :focus overriding .current, it _should_ do that while the user has focus on that element. I've updated the answer, but I say again here that I don't suggest overriding default :focus behaviour

Answer (score -1):

The blurElement() method/solution you present is definitely bad for accessibility. When activating a link or button via the keyboard controls, the blurElement() method blurs focus and the user loses their keyboard focus. Focus is thrown back to the window, and the user has to navigate back to where they were - this is terribly frustrating for keyboard users.

The link and button focus issues between FF and Chrome are irritating, but I wouldn't call them a showstopper.

Comment: The OP specifically used the mouseup event to trigger the blurElement() method, so keyboard usage would not be affected. -1